# SQL Equivalence Multiple OR's VS Several IN's

Tags: sql

Given the same rows in the table. Is this SQL query:

```
select * from table where (a in (0,1) and b in (0,2) and c in (0,3))
```

Logically equivalent to this one:

```
select * from table where
(a = 0 and b = 0 and c = 0)
or 
(a = 1 and b = 0 and c = 0)
or 
(a = 0 and b = 2 and c = 0)
or 
(a = 0 and b = 0 and c = 3)
or 
(a = 1 and b = 2 and c = 0)
or 
(a = 0 and b = 2 and c = 3)
or 
(a = 1 and b = 0 and c = 3)
or 
(a = 1 and b = 2 and c = 3);
```

????

Comment: is this a trick question?

Comment: Nope. Not sure why all the downvotes :/

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Since you are asking about *logical* equivalence...

`IN` translates to a series of `OR`'s, so:

```
a in (0,1)    →    a = 0 or a = 1
b in (0,2)    →    b = 0 or b = 2
c in (0,3)    →    c = 0 or c = 3
```

Making the following substitutions:

```
a = 0    →    A0
a = 1    →    A1
b = 0    →    B0
b = 2    →    B2
c = 0    →    C0
c = 3    →    C3
and      →    ∧
or       →    ∨
```

and taking into account [conjunction's distributivity with disjunction](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Logical_conjunction#Properties), i.e.

```
X ∧ (Y ∨ Z)  ⇔  (X ∧ Y) ∨ (X ∧ Z)
```

you get this:

```
  (A0 ∨ A1) ∧ (B0 ∨ B2) ∧ (C0 ∨ C3) ⇒
⇒ ((A0 ∨ A1) ∧ (B0 ∨ B2) ∧ C0) ∨ ((A0 ∨ A1) ∧ (B0 ∨ B2) ∧ C3) ⇒
⇒ ((A0 ∨ A1) ∧ B0 ∧ C0) ∨ ((A0 ∨ A1) ∧ B2 ∧ C0) ∨
∨ ((A0 ∨ A1) ∧ B0 ∧ C3) ∨ ((A0 ∨ A1) ∧ B2 ∧ C3) ⇒
⇒ (A0 ∧ B0 ∧ C0) ∨ (A1 ∧ B0 ∧ C0) ∨ (A0 ∧ B2 ∧ C0) ∨ (A1 ∧ B2 ∧ C0) ∨
∨ (A0 ∧ B0 ∧ C3) ∨ (A1 ∧ B0 ∧ C3) ∨ (A0 ∧ B2 ∧ C3) ∨ (A1 ∧ B2 ∧ C3)
```

Translating the final result back, you get your second query's condition.

Answer (score 0):

Logically?  Yes.  But they may have <strike>*vastly*</strike> different performance.  The first only has to check *three* conditions (at worst), which the second may have to check *eight*.  Not to say one is better than the other, as there are a lot of factors when determining performance.

Comment: Do you have any evidence that this would result in *vastly* different performance?  In my experience, the performance difference would be so negligible as to be difficult to measure.

Comment: I said _may_, not _would_.  A lot depends on the density of the data, indexes invovled, etc.  My point was they will have the same _results_ but not necessarily the same _plan_ or _performance_.  In fairness, though, I've struck the unnecessary (an presumptive) adverb.